# How to add a child node with jqTree

Tags: jquery, jqtree

I'm trying to add a new node into an existing node in jqTree (http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/), but I'm stumped.

If I have a tree like this

```
-A
 -B
 -C
  -C1
  -C2
 -D
```

...and want to add a new node as a child node of `B`, how do I do it?

The documentation talks about `addNodeAfter`, `addNodeBefore` and `addParentNode`, but I want `addChildNode` or something similar?!

I guess I'm just missing it in the documentation somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't you simply need [`appendNode`](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#functions-appendnode)?

Comment: How the *beep* did I miss that?  I must have looked at the available function about 20 times and still not seen it.  Thank you!

Comment: @MadSkunk: thank _you_ for pointing me to jqTree, which I didn't know :-)